# query optimization with NOT IN

Tags: sql

We have one main table with 10000 records with 5000 records as `status=completed` and another 5000 records `status=incompleted`.

The application maintains different category of people...say `users,visitors,admin`..

Visitors are very less(say 200 records)...as and when they purchase something the `appid` in application gets updated with status=completed.

We need `appid` of the visitors who have `status!=completed`

I know that the direct way is good performance..(below one)

```
select appid 
from application 
where status != completed and appid in (select appid from visitors)
```

`appid` also contains in visitors and as well as in application.. as application contains 5000 completed and 5000 incompleted

`NOT IN (select appid from application where status=completed)` is also same performance as with `IN (select appid from application where status=incompleted)`

```
select v.appid 
from visitors v 
where v.appid not in (select appid from application where status = completed)
```

Is my second query gives same performance with 1 st query..

if `NOT IN` execution is like this..then it is..

I am writing statement below.

```
for each v.appid in visitors{ 
  do not select the v.appid if v.appid is in by firing the query as below.

    select appid 
    from application 
    where appid = v.appid and status = completed
}
```

will the second query fire the above procedure that i mentioned...

to provide better performance same as with 1 st query can i write the below one..

```
select v.appid 
from visitors v 
where v.appid not in (select appid 
                      from application 
                      where status = completed and appid = v.appid)
```

How can I write second query so that it performs same level as 1 st query?

Comment: Is there any reason not using JOINS

Comment: Which RDBMS is this on?

Comment: @DavidAldridge oracle dbms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
select v.appid 
from visitors v 
where not exists
(select 1
 from application a
 where a.status = 'completed' and a.appid = v.appid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS instead to make query more readable and efficient. First query will convert into:

```
select 
      a.appid 
from 
      application a INNER JOIN 
      visitors v ON a.appid = v.appid 
where 
      a.status!='completed'
```

With current DB servers, interms of performance, it doesn't matter much unless you are having large number of rows with many tables.

Comment: This will give an error because `appid` is ambiguous. It might also give an error on `status`. When selecting from multiple tables, I just never specify a column without the table alias, regardless of whether it's ambiguous.

Comment: this might not give the same result at all as an `IN` sub query

Comment: @Magnus, How does it not give same result as IN sub query. INNER JOIN will get only visitors and WHERE condition filters out based on status.

Comment: Join will give duplicate rows if the same key exists multiple times (appid), `In` and `Exists` will not